# Демон оповещений (фоновая программа) на Java

Tags: java, c++, бот, демон

Недавно начал изучать тему ботов ВК, Телеграм и других соц сетей. У них есть одна проблема: чтобы увидеть оповещение об появлении новой информации на каком-либо сайте (том же YouTube) нужно быть активным в соответствующей соц-сети или запустить браузер.

Можно ли совместить такого бота с оповещениями и демона (сервис), который бы отслеживал появление новых видео на интересных мне каналах и поверх всех запущенных окон запускал оповещение?

Можно ли как-то отследить обновление информации на сайте программно? Какую библиотеку (пакет) следует изучить для подобной работы с сайтом?

P.S. Лучше знаю Java, чем С++, поэтому хотелось бы найти реализацию на Java, но если на С++ по каким-то причинам легче реализовать данную задачу, объясните, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно то что ты описываешь вполне возможно.
за ютуб не скажу но вк, телеграм советую смотреть в сторону api данных сетей.
Либо регулярные http запросы (принцип как у парсеров - парсишь страницу раз в 10 секунд если появился новый элемент вызываешь в новом потоке открытие окна-уведмления)
Kибо использовать api
https://vk.com/dev/first_guide
https://core.telegram.org/
На java есть готовые библиотеки для работы с api telegram и vk